# Arch Linux ARM - KDE Plasma Desktop - Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted

Tags: archlinux, xorg

Arch Linux ARM on Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) KDE Plasma Desktop

I get this error:

```
startx
```

---

```
X.Org X Server 1.20.9
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
Current Operating System: Linux linux 5.4.59-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 20 14:33:43 UTC 2020 armv7l
Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 snd_bcm2835.enable_headphones=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=DC:A6:32:XX:XX:XX vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootwait console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 selinux=0 plymouth.enable=0 smsc95xx.turbo_mode=N dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 kgdboc=ttyS0,115200 elevator=noop
Build Date: 26 August 2020  06:52:47AM
 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Aug 27 11:40:30 2020
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

---

```
Cont+C
```

---

```
^Cxinit: connection to X server lost
waiting for X server to shut down xterm: fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) or KillClient on X server ":0"
xterm: fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) or KillClient on X server ":0"
XIO:  fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server ":0"
      after 1140 requests (1140 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
xterm: fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) or KillClient on X server ":0"
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

xinit: unexpected signal
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using archlinux? This is not a beginners OS and assumes some expertise - I suggest you try *Raspberry Pi OS* - for which you are more likely to get some help.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS is 32-bit. Spotify is not supported and some other issues.

Comment: What does the log file say? || Might be easier to just do a reinstall.

Comment: First time I see `Ctrl` written as `Cont`